# How to move index.php jquery script to template.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla3.0

I have designed a Joomla 3.8.11 template which is using Bootstrap 4x. The template index.php has a small script just before the closing body tag with three lines to add some Bootstrap 4 code to a few elements:

```
<script>
$( ".sidenav > ul" ).addClass( "menu navbar-nav" );
$( ".separator" ).addClass( "text-hide" );
$( ".divider" ).addClass( "d-sm-none d-md-block" );
</script>
```

The first posts I found on this subject suggested just creating a javascript file and then inserting the above code after first simply stripping away the wrapping script tags and then calling it in the index.php file like this:

```
<script src='/js/menu.js'></script>
```

But it doesn't work.

Ideally, though, rather than having yet another js file, I would like to move the code into either of the existing js files - custom.js or template.js - instead. Trouble is, I am a very new beginner in jquery and javascript and I cannot get it to work in either of those files.

I have tried umpteen options like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".sidenav > ul" ).addClass( "menu navbar-nav" );
    $( ".separator" ).addClass( "text-hide" );
    $( ".divider" ).addClass( "d-sm-none d-md-block" );
});
```

and then, (trying it with just one of the lines):

```
function myTexhide() {
   var element = document.getElementsByTagName("separator");
   element.addClass( "text-hide" );
}
```

and the same with single quotes instead of double.

Then this version:

```
jQuery(window).ready(function(){
$( ".separator" ).addClass( "text-hide" );
});
```

and this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( '.separator' ).addClass( 'text-hide' );
});
```

But nothing seems to work.

I am obviously missing something. The wrong code or wrong combination of code wrapping the instructions. Any help gratefully received.

Thank you.

Comment: do you get any errors in you console?n

Comment: What is the console error it throwing?did u included jquery plugin?if you have any fiddler, please share with us you may get swift response

Comment: Sorry for the delay responding.
Jquery: I have `code`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`code` in my index.php as part of the Bootstrap 4x setup. 
I haven't looked at console errors yet but it would help if I knew exactly how I should be writing the code in a js file. I don't think I have the correct syntax. As you can see from above I have tried several different options and I have no idea if any of them are correct in the first place.

Comment: All my attempts show this console error: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: Just to clarify, all the above attempts at javascript code have been tested on their own with no other code in the file.

Comment: Syntax error: my mistake in referencing menu.js in the index.php file when the folder js is already referenced in the templateDetails.xml file. I have removed the reference from index.php and the error no longer shows up. So, no console errors, just nothing happening.